# Stored procedure using cursors

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursors

I am attempting to create a procedure using cursors to list the average salary of all employees on a per department basis. I am using three tables, defined as

- `emp` (eid, ename, age, salary)
- `works` (eid, did, pct_time)
- `dept` (did, dname, budget, managerid)

The procedure is compiling with errors. What am I doing wrong? Please see the procedure definition below.

```
create or replace procedure get_avgSalary(ddept_id in dept.did%type) 
is
  cursor c1 is
    select avg(e.salary) 
    from emp e, works w, dept d 
    where e.eid=w.eid and d.did = w.did 
    group by w.did;
  avg_sal c1%rowtype;
begin
  for avg_sal in c1 loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Average salary of the employees in department ' || ddept_id ||' is '|| avg_sal.salary);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

***I have to use a cursor. It is part of my assignment.***

Comment: Why are you using a loop?  That looks like it could be easily accomplished in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to output `avg_sal.salary` which is not defined. Use alias in the cursor body :

`.... cursor c1 is  select avg(e.salary)  AS salary ...`

Side notes. 
 It seems that parameter passed (`ddept_id` ) is not used anywhere inside the procedure except printing. Also, it's been long time since `JOIN` syntax was introduced and it's much more readable compared to SQL89 style (and recommended by Oracle as well). Finally, using cursor in this case seems quite questionable to me...

Comment: I did give it an alias and it compiles fine but it doesn't  print the average salary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  First off, I don't think you need a procedure/function to solve your problem.  Second, I definitely don't see how a cursor should come in to it.

Try the following window query using the **OVER()** clause:

```
SELECT avg(e.salary) OVER(PARTITION BY d.dname) FROM emp e, works w, dept d 
WHERE e.eid=w.eid and d.did = w.did;
```

Comment: I need to do this using a cursor. Everything is working but it does not print out the average salary. I'm a beginner to this and I have't learned the over() clause.

Comment: I have to use a cursor it part of my assignment.

Comment: Firstly, this is not a forum for solving homework assignments, but for solving actual engineering problems.  Second, if your teacher has assigned you to perform a task in a sub-optimal way, they aren't teaching you very well.

Comment: **Every** Select statement (and also any other DML or DDL statment) creates a cursor in Oracle. You can always access the default attribute, e.g. `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. Looks like your teacher does not know the difference between an implicit and an explicit cursor.

Comment: Homework questions are [not automatically off-topic on this site](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/491/1192). A good enough question is a good enough question regardless.